# Assigning a value to an input field that changes its id's dynamically

Tags: javascript

I want to assign a value to an input field which changes its id'd dynamically. The field looks like below.

```
<input aria-autocomplete="list" aria-labelledby="downshift-5-label" autocomplete="off" id="downshift-5-input" placeholder="Enter agent name" class="css-1u5bp1w etr7mik2" value="">
```

My requirement is to assign a value to this field. I have tried the below method. It shows that value appearing in the UI, but it does not assign in to the value="" field above.

```
document.querySelector('*[placeholder="Enter agent name"]').value = "bf5a4";
```

Is there any method to assign a value to this field?

Comment: why/how does the element change its id?

Comment: can you show the value appearing in UI?

Comment: I can not attach a video to show. The value that I'm passing get assigned to the input field and then it disappears. So it does not actually assigned to the value="" in the input field. And im not quite sure how that id's get changed dynamically

Comment: give a blank value initially like value="" and then using js you can  document.getElementsByClassName("abc")[0].value = "qwerty"; to change a value @SashikaWijesinghe

Answer (score 1):

HTML elements have a distinction between *attributes* and *properties*.

To put it shortly, whenever you do in javascript `element.xyz`, then you're accessing a *property* named `xyz`, as opposed to the attribute.

However, when you inspect the HTML `<>` tags, you're viewing *attributes*. So you're code correctly sets the `value` property, but you won't see `<input... value="bf5a4">` as you haven't set the `value` attribute.

If you in fact do want to set the attribute, you'll have to explicitly invoke `setAttribute` ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)), e.g.:

```js
let el = document.querySelector('*[placeholder="Enter agent name"]');

el.value = 'bf5a4-property'; // sets property
el.setAttribute('value', 'bf5a4-attribute'); // sets attribute (// <input... value="bf5a4-attribute">)
```

```html
<input aria-autocomplete="list" aria-labelledby="downshift-5-label"
       autocomplete="off" id="downshift-5-input" placeholder="Enter agent name"
       class="css-1u5bp1w etr7mik2" value="">
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried the setAttribute method as mentioned above but it does not set the value yet

Comment: All I can say without further details is: it does in my example.